# Codeigniter - form validation 2 field required with not match value

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm trying to make a validation for 2 field that must have a different value. I only know how to set the rules for validate matching value.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('book1','Book1','required|matches[book2]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('book2','Book2','required|matches[book1]');
```

if I input `book1`=`novel`, and `book2`=`novel`, the code above will return `TRUE`.

How can I validate 2 field where the value of each field is not matching each other? So if I input `book1`=`novel` and `book2`=`comic`, it will return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `callback_` method for custom validation, CI form validation library does not provide notMatch type validation rule, see below sample code.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('book1','Book1','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('book2','Book2','required|callback__notMatch[book1]');
```

AND place method in controller class

```
function _notMatch($book2Value, $book1FieldName){
   if($book2Value != $this->input->post($book1FieldName){
       $this->form_validation->set_message('_notMatch', 'book1 and book2 values are not matching');
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Just for further reading: [The CodeIgniter documentation for callbacks in form validation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Comment: thanks. I follow your code and change some of the code until I found what I want. Only replace `!=` become `==` and set my error message to `you can't choose the same book again`.

Answer (score 3):

In codeigniter 3 you can use the differs[] set rule, to enforce that field values don't match.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('book1', 'Book 1', 'required|differs[book2]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('book2', 'Book 2', 'required|differs[book1]');
```

This means you don't need to create an unnecessary callback. However, for older versions you will.

See the documentations for more: [Codeigniter 3 Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `differs` like so:

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'current password', 'max_length[25]|min_length[5]|required');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('new_password', 'new password', 'max_length[25]|min_length[5]|required|differs[password]');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'confirm password', 'required|max_length[25]|min_length[5]|matches[new_password]');
```